# Spring MVC Param Error - How to send date request to jsp

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, mapping, crud

I am using **Spring MVC 3.4.0.** When i tried CRUD example I get this error in my browser console;

> HTTP Status 400 -  The request sent by the client was syntactically
>   incorrect.

My codes:

**EditBlog.jsp**;

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>

<form  action="/testhibernate/edit/${blogID}/" method="POST" name="BLOG">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    <input name="TITLE" type="text" value="${blogList.title}" size="30"/>
     <h3>CREATE_DATE</h3>
     <input name="CREATE_DATE" type="date" value="${blogList.createDate}" size="30"/>
     <h3>TEXT_CONTENT</h3>
     <input name="TEXT_CONTENT" type="text" value="${blogList.textContent}" size="30"/>
     <br>

    <input name="action" type="submit" value="Edit" size="30"/> 
</form>
```

**editController** ;

```
package com.basari.testhibernate;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.basari.blog.Blog;
import com.basari.blog.User_Blog_App;

@Controller
public class editController {

    @Autowired
    private User_Blog_App deneme1;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{blogID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView findBlog(@PathVariable Integer blogID)
     {
      ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("editBlog");
      Blog blog= deneme1.findBlog(blogID);
      mav.addObject("blogList", blog);
      return mav;
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{blogID}/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView editBlog(@PathVariable Integer blogID

                  , @RequestParam( value = "TITLE", required=false) String title
                  , @RequestParam( value = "TEXT_CONTENT", required=false) String content
                  , @RequestParam( value = "CREATE_DATE", required=false) Date date


     ) {
           Blog blog= deneme1.findBlog(blogID);


             blog.setTitle( title );
             blog.setTextContent( title );
             blog.setCreateDate(date);

             this.deneme1.editBlog( blog );

             ContactController.logger.debug( "contactPost action called ");

             try{


             }finally{

             }
             ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("editBlog");
             mav.addObject("blogList", blog);
             return mav;


     }

}
```

**edit Function** ;

```
public void editBlog(Blog blog){

    Session session =sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx= null;

    try{
        tx= session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(blog);
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(HibernateException e){

        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 

    }finally{
        session.close();
    }       

}
```

And there is no error in my JAVA console. What is wrong?

Comment: When you are getting error on button `submit` or before that? If you are getting error after clicking `submit` then record is updated in DB or not? and plz post url from address bar where you are getting error

Comment: What value do you enter for the `CREATE_DATE` field?

Comment: When i click button i get this error at this url : http://localhost:8080/testhibernate/edit/4

Comment: I am entering date type

Comment: That doesn't help. What value do you enter in the `<input>` field? If anything, open up your browser's Network Console and check what is sent in the HTTP request.

Comment: This is what i send http://i40.tinypic.com/es6o2f.png and this is Network Console when i click "edit" = http://i41.tinypic.com/2jf0i2p.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is almost certainly that Spring cannot convert the date you enter in this `<input>` field

```
 <input name="CREATE_DATE" type="date" value="${blogList.createDate}" size="30"/>
```

into an argument to pass to

```
 @RequestParam( value = "CREATE_DATE", required=false) Date date
```

As a result, the request is a Bad Request and Spring returns you a 400 status code.

Add a `@DateTimeFormat` annotation to your request parameter. For example,

```
 @RequestParam( value = "CREATE_DATE", required=false) @DateTimeFormat("dd-MM-yyyy") Date date
```

And then make sure your client sends the appropriate format of date. For example

```
14-01-2014
```

Comment: i use datimeformat(patten="dd-mm-yyyy") and in network console it look like this ------WebKitFormBoundaryXkUiV2UDcRBQvQZp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CREATE_DATE"

2014-01-15       And i tried this controller without createdate and i got this error again

Comment: @hurricane Try adding an `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` to your `<form>`. You are sending a multipart request which I don't think your server is setup to handle correctly. Also, if you are sending `2014-01-15`, you will need to use a date format of `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: Now i am trying enctype="multipart/form-data" in form . I think i have to configure in bean this form. Thank you for this path

Answer (score 3):

Try this It will work for you
In your controller

```
@InitBinder

protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat,false));

}
```